# My and my brother's education... ?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am not convinced with this sentence somehow.
" My Dad focused on my and my brother's education"
It doesn't sound right to me. How can I write it in a better way?

Comment: It's a chain dupe.

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that the construction is considered clumsy in English. We can go for the avoidance strategies:

**repetition**: my education and my brother's education

**using the possessive pronoun**: my brother's education and mine

**avoiding the possessive**: the education of my brother and myself